# How to get the hyperlink destinations for the results of this web search

Tags: selenium-webdriver, webdriver, screen-scraping

I'm trying to write a Python script to scrape the hyperlink destinations (i.e., the href values) for each one of the entries in this web of science search results:

https://www.webofscience.com/wos/woscc/summary/6224cee5-30d2-4e62-8729-212ea8f51522-c6c4cc63/times-cited-descending/1

I would like to do it using Selenium in combination with Microsoft Edge WebDriver. I already have Selenium and Edge WebDriver installed. I have had partial success using searches such as

```
elements = driver.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME,'a[data-ta="summary-record-title-link"]')
print(len(elements))
for element in elements:
    print(element.get_attribute('href'))
```

But for some reason, I can only get the href values for the first 4 search results, when in fact there are 50 search results on the webpage. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You should use playwright instead of selenium, playwright is a much newer python library and does NOT require a webdriver, in addition, it allows web scraping elements like "href" to be much easier. It works for chrome, msedge, firefox, chromium, and webkit. [Click here](https://playwright.dev/python/docs/intro) to see installation and documentation.

Comment: The code you use is generally correct, except for the locator type. You are using By.TAG_NAME, but providing a CSS selector, so it should be By.CSS_SELECTOR. Also, you use 'find_elements' which may be a problem for the 'dynamically loaded' websites. Before collecting the anchor tags ensure that your page is fully loaded. You can use WebDriverWait and expected_conditions for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was, as I later found out, that I needed to ask Selenium to scroll down. Since the webpage is dynamically loaded, content is only present once you scroll down. Alternatively, you can ask Selenium to change the zoom factor to make the elements visible.

To scroll down to the bottom of the screen:

```
# Scrolls down to the bottom of the page.
driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
```

To change the zoom factor:

```
# Changes the zoom of the page to 10%.
driver2.execute_script("document.body.style.zoom='10%'")
```